# How to fix user information not logging into database?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a Discord bot that logs user info to database when they post their first message in a guild that the bot is in (previously I had a command for that, but it wasn't very easy to use). The database is crucial for my bot because of economy commands.

I have this script for logging user info into the database if the user isn't there yet

```
  client.on('message', message => {
  if (db.has(`@${message.author.id}.Inventory`)) {
  // DO STUFF
  }
  else {
  db.push(`${message.author.id}.Inventory`, `Bread`)
  }
});
```

This script should produce this in the database.json file

```
"userID": {
   "Inventory": [
   "Bread"
   ]
}
```

I use userIDs for logging the users in the database, because they can't change. The database I am using is simpl.db.

This code doesn't work and I can't figure out why. It works fine when I restart the bot and right after I post a message -> It adds the user to the database. But if I have the bot online and I send other messages from accounts that already are in the database, the bot ignores the user that isn't in the database.

Like this:

BOT STARTED -> MESSAGE SENT BY USER WHO ISNT'IN DATABASE -> LOGS INTO DATABASE

BOT STARTED -> MESSAGE SENT BY USER WHO IS IN DATABASE -> IGNORES (as it should) -> MESSAGE SENT BY A USER WHO IS NOT IN DATABASE -> IGNORES (shouldn't do that...)

So it only ignores the user if an another message has been posted before the user that isn't in the database can post a message. So only the first user that posts a message after startup is checked.

Sorry if I explained it badly, but I tried to put it as well as I can :)

Comment: The if condition is missing a `)`

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right. But that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: If you fix that, does it fix the problem, or no?

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: So what is happening now?

Comment: The same problem as before.

Comment: Can you replace //DO STUFF with actual code? If you have anything private there, like a password, you can censor it out by replacing it

Comment: I will add the code here later today.